# Shell script get file name that does not end with _0.xml

Tags: linux, bash

I need help.
i have the following in a shell script

```
FILES_TO_VALIDATE=$FTP_DEST/patternorderresponse_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_UTC*.xml
```

this will get all the files like

```
patternorderresponse_2023165_UTC1633_0.xml
patternorderresponse_2023165_UTC1633_12.xml
patternorderresponse_2023165_UTC1633_22212.xml
```

etc.

i would like to exclude the ones that end in `_0.xml`

How can i do that?

Comment: If it _really is_ bash, `shopt -s extglob`  and then you can refer to `...[0-9]_UTC!(*_0).xml`. That doesn't work for `/bin/sh`.

Comment: BTW, it's safer to store a list of files in an array. If you use `files_to_validate=( "$FTP_DEST"/... )`, then you can `for file in "${files_to_validate[@]}"; do [[ $file = *_0.xml ]] && continue; ...; done` to store everything in the array but then filter out the things you don't want before acting on them. The big advantage of the array there is that it works correctly with filenames that would mess up regular unquoted glob expansion.

Comment: Hello Charles,

i have tryed with

shopt -s extglob !*_0.xml

FILES_TO_VALIDATE=/var/opt/core/env/current/domain/data/save/in/hermes/patternorderresponse_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_UTC*.xml

and is showin the error:

line 3: shopt: !*_0.xml: invalid shell option name

Comment: this works


for i in `ls -tr $FILES_TO_VALIDATE`
do
 if [[ $i = *_0.xml ]]
    then
       echo $i
      continue;
    fi
    echo next
done;

Comment: Do see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003), and [BashFAQ #99](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099).

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` is a complete command on its own, it doesn't take your glob as a later argument. It just turns on the parser feature that makes `!(*_0)` work, the `!(*_0)` isn't part of the `shopt` command; the glob should be part of a `for` loop or an array assignment or whatever else as appropriate.

Comment: Without using _extglob_, I would store the list based on your pattern into an **array** (which makes more sense anyway, if you one day get files with spaces in the name), and then loop over the array and remove the unwanted element.